# Java Constructor variables being ignored

Tags: java

I am trying to create a instance of the object Iset. When the person makes the object they have to give an int which will be the size of a boolean array that will store a set of integers e.g 1 will be Iset[1] = true etc etc.  But I keep getting index out of range error. The rest of the program is obviously ignoring the values I set in the constructor so how do I make sure that the values I use in the constructor are used in all of my methods?

First part of the code:

```
 public class Iset {
    public int size;
    boolean[] Iset;


    ISet(int a) {
        int size = a;
        seti = new boolean[size];
```

Comment: You mean `this.size=a` ?

Comment: You're shadowing the a variable.

Comment: More compilable code, please.

Comment: Where is the error ? Your code is probably buggy but we don't see enough.

Comment: You don't need to `save` the size since you can always get the value from `Iset.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets have a look at your code :

```
 public class Iset {
    public int size;// Declares a Member of a class and all the objects will have a copy of this member
    boolean[] Iset;
.....
}


    ISet(int a) {
        int size = a; //This line is declaring a **local variable** called size 
        seti = new boolean[size];
...
}
```

See in your constructor you've created a local variable `size` but you also have a class member called `size`  in your class. So in this scenario whenever we try to set `size` variable within constructor, there arises a conflict to the compiler whether to set the local variable or the class member ( this conflict is because of the fact that both the local variable and class member has same name ) . **In such scenarios the compiler chooses local variable size over the class member size**. But for you to make sure that the values you use in the constructor are used in all of my methods, **you have to set the class member**. To set the class member we use following code:

```
this.size = a;//Says set the object member size to value present in a.
```

Here we refer the size using **this** pointer **because we need to set the object's size variable and not the local variable size**.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new variable inside your constructor and this is called *shadowing*. Use `this` to set the attributes of the current object:

```
this.size = a;
```

Comment: It would certainly fix bugs but this doesn't really explain the error.

Comment: I don't see this causing index out of range, though.

Comment: Would I then need to use this. for each other instance of size or would that be ok?

Comment: @APD "this" always refers to the object whose code executed currently. So when setting the instance variables always use "this" to prevent confusions.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `int` variable inside the constructor. Instead, you just need to do `this.size = a;` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Iset {
    public int size;
    boolean[] seti;


    ISet(int a) {
        this.size = a; // This will make methods access the value
        this.seti = new boolean[size];
```

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: oops sorry for the typo. I have modified the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `this` keyword, an make the constructor **public** if you want to instantiate it in another class:

```
public class ISet {
    public int size;
    boolean[] iSet;


    public ISet(int a) {
        this.size = a;
        this.iSet = new boolean[a];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`size` variable in your constructor is a local variable, that's why other member methods doesn't get the right size to check.

Assign the value to `this.size`, then it will work:

```
ISet(int a) {
        this.size = a;
        seti = new boolean[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the **size instance variable** properly, instead you are initializing a **local variable size**. Therefore your **size instance variable** remained initialized with **0** and your **seti instance variable** is an **empty** array causing the out of range error.
As pointed out by others, you don't need the instance variable size. 
There is also no need for another local variable size inside your constructor, Just use **seti.length** to determine the size of the array.  To simplify, your code should be:

```
public class Iset {
boolean[] seti;

ISet(int a) {
    seti = new boolean[a];
```

I would recommend you use static analysis tools like checkstyle to eliminate bug like this in your codes.